# Within an iOS app how do I detect that the user has pressed one of the arrow keys on their external keyboard?

Tags: ios, keyboard, bluetooth, arrow-keys

I have a couple of iOS applications which present inherently linearly organised information, allowing the user to move forward and backward through the data with on-screen controls.  I would like to allow users with the keyboard dock or a paired bluetooth keyboard to use the arrow keys to move back and forth as well.  Since the apps are full-screen it is very important to the user experience that there is no risk of displaying an on-screen keyboard as a side-effect.

I cannot find an API that will let me do this in Apple's documentation; but I cannot be sure that I have used the right search terms.

What APIs are there which will allow me to achieve this?

**Update:** I have raised this as an enhancement on [Apple's bug reporting site](http://bugreport.apple.com).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Not actually knowing, I suspect the answer is "you can't, not in an official way".

Since a user-friendly UI is top priority for the iPad platform according to Apple, I think they are doing what they can to discourage behavior that would depend on a keyboard being available. Apps should behave the same and provide the same functionality with or without a hardware keyboard. Things like keyboard hotkeys or navigation that doesn't use on-screen elements are probably no-no:s for that reason.

But, like I said, this is just speculation.

Comment: He's not trying to require a keyboard, just make the app usable without removing one's hands from the keyboard if you _do_ have one. That's an _increase_ in user-friendliness.

Comment: @Nicholas Yep, I see what he wants to do, and I'm not saying it's wrong in any way. :) As there is a "Next" key on the soft keyboard, something similar should be doable from a hard keyboard as well. But I suspect that using keyboard shortcuts to, for example, present new view controllers would go against the iPad philosophy.

Comment: Also (playing the devils advocate here) having apps be more user friendly when a hard keyboard is present might not be what Apple feels is the best for the platform... They likely want to downplay the need of external peripherals. But this all has nothing to do with the actual question. :)

Answer (score 3):

You can easily determine which arrow keys are pressed by referring to `UIKeyInput` and `UIKeyInputDelegate`. The method you're looking for specifically is `positionFromPosition:inDirection:offset:`.

After that method is called (it is used by iOS to determine the selection range) it will then call `setSelectedText:`. Put `NSLog` statements in the `positionFromPosition:inDirection:offset:` to determine how it works (you're responsible for the plumbing).

Also look at the [SimpleTextInput](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SimpleTextInput/Introduction/Intro.html). This will provide you with a template on subclassing `UITextInput`.

Comment: What about with an empty UITextView? This works for the left and right arrow keys, but I couldn't find a way to separately identify the up and down keys--they both output the same things for `NSLog`.

Answer (score 3):

The answer in [How can I respond to external keyboard arrow keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7980447/how-can-i-respond-to-external-keyboard-arrow-keys?rq=1) - create a hidden text field and react to selection changes - worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You could eliminate the keyboard entirely by just adding support for a left/right swipe or drag gesture so the user can essentially treat the app like a photo gallery. No onscreen controls are needed-- it's a device-native navigation paradigm, easy to explain on an app startup splash screen.

If an external keyboard is **required** in order to support other app data-gathering functionality however, users will experience the "gorilla arm" problem...