# How can I support the arrow keys on UIWebView with a Bluetooth keyboard under?

Tags: ios, iphone, uiwebview, codemirror, arrow-keys

Part of arrow keys don't do anything on some pages. For example on CodeMirror editor: http://codemirror.net/demo/fullscreen.html

How do you support all arrow keys from an external keyboard in `UIWebView`?

Comment: This is solution for similar problem on native UI:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7980447/how-can-i-respond-to-external-keyboard-arrow-keys/8036524#8036524
It works for both external and on-screen keyboard.

Comment: And how it's supposed to work with `UIWebView`? No relation to the question at all.

Comment: It's a direction on how it works. You can add a text view to the master view, and pass keyboard events to UIWebView

Comment: But how to pass other key events to the `UIWebView`?

Answer (score -1):

In answer to your question on my post in another thread [How can I respond...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19607933/558575), the keyCommands property is a property on UIResponder and UIWebView inherits from UIResponder so I can see no reason why it won't work.

Comment: On `UIWebView` `keyCommands` works but `@selectors` don't execute. How can I solve this?

Comment: So how are you seeing that keyCommands works if your @selectors don't execute?

Comment: It seems your ^^ method only works while in the TextField. What if I want the "Right Arrow" to close my web view or move to my History for instance?